# asp.net for C# : treeview's expandImage and collapseImage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had created the TreeLineImages folder and set my image in the folder.
It is working for the collapseimage/expandimage in asp.net  page.

However, every collapseimage/expandimage is the same in my TreeView.
I want to give a special collapseimage/expandimage image for root's Node.
Can I?

```
  <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" OnTreeNodePopulate="TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate" NodeIndent="15" ShowLines="True" LineImagesFolder="~/TreeLineImages">
                  <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="../images/treeview/dot.gif" />
                </asp:TreeView>
```

I think that I should show my photo to make my question more understandable.
I want to change root's collapse image/expand image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just set the `TreeView` Collapse Image URL property like

```
TreeView1.CollapseImageUrl = "Your_Collapse_Image_Path";
TreeView1.ExpandImageUrl = "Your_Expand_Image_Path";
```

Or setting as fixed image in both collapse and expand actions in the design mode with html like:

```
<asp:TreeNode **ImageUrl**="~/Styles/nodeImg.jpg" Text="New Node" Value="New Node"></asp:TreeNode>
```

Comment: this is not the answer which I want...I want to know how to change root's collapse image/expand image.Not node's imageurl. Thanks for your replay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use the LevelStyles collection, it represents the node styles at the individual levels of the tree.

```
   <asp:TreeView id="TreeView"
    ExpandDepth="3"   NodeIndent="0" Runat="server">

    <LevelStyles>

      <asp:TreeNodeStyle ImageUrl="../images/treeview/dot.gif"/>
      <asp:TreeNodeStyle ImageUrl="../images/treeview/dot.gif2"/>

    </LevelStyles>

    <Nodes>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="One">

        <asp:TreeNode Text="Two">
    </Nodes>
 </asp:TreeView>
```

The first style in the collection corresponds to the style of nodes in the first level of the tree. The second style in the collection corresponds to the style of nodes in the second level of the tree, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know what you mean.I add a photo to describe my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem like you. and solve this by this solution. i hope that helpful for you.

```html
<asp:TreeView runat="server" LineImagesFolder="~/Images"></asp:TreeView>
```

1- Set property "LineImagesFolder" of Tree View example:
LineImagesFolder="~/Images"
2- then all of image that Tree View needed to it copy into this address of your solution. ex : l.gif, r.gif, rplus.gif, rminus.gif, lplus.gif, lminus.gif, plus.gif, minus.gif and etc.
(however if you replace custom expand and collapse image url, in this folder is Enough. if view inspect of html code detect that what image is neede for some element of treeview)

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
              <asp:TreeView id="CustomTreeView"
        NoExpandImageUrl="Space.jpg"
        CollapseImageUrl="Minus.png"
        CollapseImageToolTip="Collapse Node"
        ExpandImageUrl="Plus.jpg"
        ExpandImageToolTip="Expand Node"
        RootNodeStyle-ImageUrl="Root.jpg"
        ParentNodeStyle-ImageUrl="Parent.jpg"
        LeafNodeStyle-ImageUrl="Leaf.jpg" 
        ImageSet="Custom"
        runat="server">

        <Nodes>

          <asp:TreeNode Value="Home" 
            NavigateUrl="Home.aspx" 
            Text="Home"
            Target="_blank" 
            Expanded="True">

            <asp:TreeNode Value="Page 1" 
              NavigateUrl="Page1.aspx" 
              Text="Page 1"
              Target="_blank">

              <asp:TreeNode Value="Section 1"
                ImageUrl="custom.jpg" 
                NavigateUrl="Section1.aspx" 
                Text="Section 1"
                Target="_blank">
              </asp:TreeNode>

            </asp:TreeNode>

            <asp:TreeNode Value="Page 2" 
              Selected="True" 
              NavigateUrl="Page2.aspx"
              Text="Page 2"
              Target="_blank">
            </asp:TreeNode>

          </asp:TreeNode>

        </Nodes>

      </asp:TreeView>
```